# Check for values in multidimensional input array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I store values in a multi-dimensional hidden input array that looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tokens[0][Search_Type]" value="a" />
<input type="hidden" name="tokens[0][Search_Term]" value="123" />
<input type="hidden" name="tokens[1][Search_Type]" value="b" />
<input type="hidden" name="tokens[1][Search_Term]" value="456" />
```

How can I quickly check whether there is a `token` with `Search_Term` = X and `Search_Type` = Y?  If there's a way to do it in one jquery line rather than in a loop that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery:

```
token_found = $('input[name$=Search_Type]][value=Y]
                 +
                 input[name$=Search_Term]][value=X]'
               ).length > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with selectors as well:

```js
// found
console.log($('input[name$="[Search_Type]"][value="a"]').next('input[name$="[Search_Term]"][value="123"]').length); 

// not found
console.log($('input[name$="[Search_Type]"][value="b"]').next('input[name$="[Search_Term]"][value="123"]').length); 

// found
console.log($('input[name$="[Search_Type]"][value="b"]').next('input[name$="[Search_Term]"][value="456"]').length);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/56jLf/

But whether or not that is more efficient than with looping, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking the submitted array as a javascript object, you can use [jsonpath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to perform xpath like queries on a dataset.