# Help with jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check for values in multidimensional input array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239925/check-for-values-in-multidimensional-input-array)

I'm using a jQuery selector to look for duplicate tokens in a set of input tags that looks like this:

```
<ul id="class-items">
 <li>
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens[0][Search_Type]" value="a" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens[0][Search_Term]" value="123" />
 </li>
 <li>
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens[1][Search_Type]" value="b" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens[1][Search_Term]" value="456" />
 </li>
</ul>
```

This is my jQuery selector check for duplicate tokens, which doesn't seem to be working:

```
if ($('#class-items > li > input[name$="Search_Type"][value="' + searchType + '"] + input[name$="Search_Term"][value="' + searchTerm + '"]').length == 0)
```

I know that the hidden tokens are adding correctly as I can see from viewing the DOM source.

Comment: Elaborate on *duplicate tokens*.

Comment: Isn't this the same as you asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239925/check-for-values-in-multidimensional-input-array ?

Comment: @Niklas Yes, now I'm just trying to debug

Comment: in that case, you should have done it in the previous question.

Comment: @Niklas, fair enough, I kind of figured that people wouldn't view the old one after a day though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `name` attributes do not end with `Search_Type` and `Search_Term`.

They have a `]` at the end, so the selector should use `Search_Type]` and `Search_Term]`, as in:

```
     // -------------------------------------v
'#class-items > li > input[name$="Search_Type]"][value="' + 
  searchType + '"] + input[name$="Search_Term]"][value="' + 
  searchTerm + '"]'
```

Comment: I was about 2 seconds from pressing the 'Post Your Answer' button with this... darnit :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the inputs simpler names (e.g. `input1`..) to make it's not that that's causing your problems?

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting up your selector to be sure that the `+` operator correctly matches elements at the same level:

```
$('#class-items > li').find('input[name$="Search_Type]"][value="' + searchType + '"] +
                             input[name$="Search_Term]"][value="' + searchTerm + '"]')
```

NB: per someone else's comment to your question, also your `name$=` terms are incorrect because they omitted the trailing square bracket.